# Deploy an application to Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to deploy an application to Google Kubernetes Engine(GKE) but I confused between 
(1) pull a new commit from a master branch from git server inside a container
(2) pull a new image that's included new commit from docker hub

Which is the best solution for cost and performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting code on GitHub/Bitbucket, consider just using Google Container Builder to trigger a new build on every commit and build/push the docker image and deploy it to GKE.

If you're not on github, you can use something like GitOps https://www.weave.works/blog/gitops-high-velocity-cicd-for-kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Github Actions, Gitlab CICD or Bitbucket for setting up a CICD pipeline.

For example, Gitlab connects with your GKE using OAuth and gives you the ability to build, test, lint, review and deploy in different environments.

If you want to explore more on how to use Gitlab CICD to Deploy a mono-repo of microservices consider reading https://medium.com/@arslan_53972/application-deployment-using-gitlab-ci-cd-on-managed-kubernetes-cluster-at-gcp-72b59496979c

Answer (score 0):

Recent [GitLab version (13.4 or more) have a GitLab Kubernetes Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040692/6309), but not for the Community Edition.

Even if you do it manually, you will need to monitor the cost of that deployment, as illustrated by the question "[How to clean up after a GKE cluster created with gcloud container clusters create?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59129958/6309)".

For that, see [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#view-cluster-cost-management-data-in-gitlab) (October 2020)

> ### View cluster cost management data in GitLab
>
> Many users created their own scripts to better understand their cluster costs. However, now you can see an overview of your cluster costs and resource usage in the GitLab user interface. Our integration builds on Kubecost’s `cost-model` and gives you flexible insights into various levels of your clusters. Use the provided cost template to see your monthly node costs and the costs of your GitLab Managed Apps, or build more elaborate custom dashboards with the nine metrics provided by Kubecost and the Prometheus query features of GitLab.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_5/cluster_cost.png -- View cluster cost management data in GitLab]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/cost_management.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/216737).

---

And [GitLab 14.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/12/22/gitlab-14-6-released/#gitlab-agents-activity-information) (December 2021) comes with:

> ### GitLab Agent’s activity information
>
> Being able to monitor your cluster’s activity helps you detect and troubleshoot faulty events, and rest assured when they succeed.
>
> GitLab now ships with an activity list for the GitLab Agent that logs real-time events. This first implementation logs connection and token statuses and will be followed with more events in future releases.
> We also plan to provide a similar solution to [track CI/CD Tunnel events](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/340484), for which your early feedback is more than welcome.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_6/gitlab_agent_activity_events_v14_6.png -- GitLab Agent's activity information]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/#view-agent-activity-information) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/340363).