# How to clean up after a GKE cluster created with gcloud container clusters create?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm creating Kubernetes clusters programmatically for end-to-end tests in GitLab CI/CD. I'm using `gcloud container clusters create`. I'm doing this for half a year and created and deleted a few hundred clusters. The cost went up and down. Now, I got an unusually high bill from Google and I checked the cost breakdown. I noticed that the cost is >95% for "Storage PD Capacity". I found out that `gcloud container clusters delete` never deleted the Google Compute Disks created for Persistent Volume Claims in the Kubernetes cluster.

How can I delete those programmatically? What else could be left running after deleting the Kubernetes cluster and the disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this part of the answer is lengthy:

```sh
gcloud compute disks create disk-a \
--size=10gb \
--zone=us-west1-a \
--labels=something=monday \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud compute disks create disk-b \
--size=10gb \
--zone=us-west1-b \
--labels=something=else \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Then:

```
ID=$(gcloud compute disks list \
--filter="name~disk zone~us-west1 labels.something=else" \
--format="value(id)" \
--project=${PROJECT}) && echo ${ID}
```

**NB**

- the filter `AND` is implicit and omitted
- you may remove terms as needed
- you should make the filter as specific as possible

And -- when you're **certain** as deletion is irrecoverable:

```
gcloud compute disks delete ${ID} --project=${PROJECT} --region=${REGION}
```

If there are multiple matches, you can iterate:

```
IDS=$(gcloud compute disks list ...)
for ID in ${IDS}
do
  gcloud compute disks delete ${ID}
done
```

If you prefer -- the awesome [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you'll have a general-purpose way (not `gcloud`-specific):

```sh
gcloud compute disks list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format=json \
| jq --raw-output '.[] | select(.name | contains("disk")) | select(.zone | contains("us-west1")) | select(.labels.something=="else")'
...
```

Comment: The disks are created by the Google Kubernetes Engine for every Persistent Volume Claim. I'd like to avoid adding vendor specific attributes to my deployment descriptors. And I'm not even sure if labels defined in Kubernetes would appear on the discs later.

Comment: Then simplify the filter to just `--filter=name~^gke-${PREFIX}`

Comment: Please note the gcloud compute disks delete command now takes the disk name, not the disk ID.

Comment: ^  I've tried to edit but the queue is full.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

1. To answer your immediate question: you can programatically delete your disk resource(s) with the [Method: disks.delete](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/delete) API.
2. To determine what other resources might have been allocated, look here: [Listing all Resources in your Hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources).
3. Finally, this link might also help: [GKE: Understanding cluster resource usage](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-usage-metering)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you an idea how to delete the disks which have been created by the cluster? I could delete all of them, but that'd make it hard to use the whole Cloud Engine for anything else than one project. Is the deletion possible through the `gcloud` command? Since I'm already using it to create and delete the cluster, it'd be much less boilerplate.

Comment: I honestly don't know.  Nor do I know how things would compare if you implemented your CI/DI cluster in MS Azure or AWS :(

Comment: Yes it is  possible to delete a disk with gcloud "gcloud compute disks delete" more info in https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/delete

Comment: The solution is to `gcloud compute disks list `--filter="..." --format="..." project=${PROJECT}` to list only those disks that match some criteria that guarantees these are the disks created by the cluster. The `--format` can be used to output only the disk ID. You can then pipe the output into `gcloud compute disks delete ...`. Do you know how to uniquely identify the PDs created by the cluster?

Comment: @DazWilkin I'd be interested in a solution how to delete exactly those disks created by the cluster which has just been deleted. Currently I'm parsing the output of `gcloud compute disks list` in a Python script which is far from elegant. I'm guessing that paulsm4 wouldn't mind if you edit point 1. of the answer. Points 2. and 3. are good references.

Comment: @karl-richter Do you know how to uniquely identify the PDs created by the cluster? Without that information, I can't provide a specific answer. I'll write you a generic answer but that's less helpful.

Comment: @DazWilkin I thought you're asking whether I'm interested in this information - no idea why I did so :). I don't know that either. Currently I'm fine with deleting all disks whose names start with `gke-[first 10 letters of my cluster name]`.